# Facebook API, AdCreative title

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-marketing-api

Two questions about AdCreative Facebook Marketing API.
1. In Facebook docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup) I can find description of "creative" field. It assume two methods of creative addition to Ad, via ID and via AdCreative spec, which can be translate to python as dict. But when I send this API call `

```
    ad = Ad(parent_id=self.parent_id)
    ad[Ad.Field.name] = advert_name
    ad[Ad.Field.adset_id] = group_id
    ad[Ad.Field.creative] = {
        "creative": {"name": advert_name, "object_story_spec": object_story_spec, "title": headline,
    "body": message, "object_url": object_url}
        # 'creative_id': creature["creative_id"],
    }
    ad_id = ad.remote_create(params={'status': Ad.Status.active})
```

`
 I receive only

```
  Response:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 100, 
    "is_transient": false, 
    "error_subcode": 1487066, 
    "error_user_msg": "No creative spec found for given adgroup.", 
    "error_user_title": "Missing creative spec", 
    "message": "Invalid parameter", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "fbtrace_id": "EQFX0HUnTKV"
  }
}
```

Where my error? Use current facebookads package.

2. How I can set title for AdCreative? Its sound very simple, but AdCreative.title in my case transformed into "Text", not into "Headline".[image]

Answer (score 0):

For second part of my own question I found a solution. This should be done via AdCreativeLinkData or AdCreativeVideoData.

- For AdCreativeVideoData this should be `title` & `message` fields
- For AdCreativeLinkData this should be `name` & `message` fields